# Recursively copy files using docker cp

Tags: docker

Does `docker` truly only support one file-at-a-time copying to/from the host?

The only options displayed for `docker cp` are:

```
 $docker cp --help

Usage:  docker cp [OPTIONS] CONTAINER:SRC_PATH DEST_PATH|-
    docker cp [OPTIONS] SRC_PATH|- CONTAINER:DEST_PATH

Copy files/folders between a container and the local filesystem

Options:
  -a, --archive       Archive mode (copy all uid/gid information)
  -L, --follow-link   Always follow symbol link in SRC_PATH
```

In addition the `jira` https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/7710 shows that *wildcards* are not presently supported .. So is the only option here to create an archive and cp / untar *that* ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

According to the [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/#extended-description):

> The cp command behaves like the Unix cp -a command in that directories are **copied recursively** with permissions preserved if possible.

This means that `docker cp` copy files recursively by default.